# Remove smell from barrel

Tags: off-flavor

What is the best way to remove a faint disinfectant smell from my pressure barrel as its tainted the smell of my lager.

I've tried white vinegar, chlorine my usual Sanitiser and just hit water but a faint smell is still there. The barrel is plastic.

Comment: I usually use lemon juice when trying to remove odors. I have yet to try it with homebrewing, but if you are willing to try it might work!

Comment: I'm with Sander--although I also haven't tried it with brewing equipment and there's a chance you'll get some citrus scent.  Maybe time for a hefe?  :D

Comment: What disinfectant did you use that has a lingering smell?

Comment: @brewchez it was Solucaps

Comment: If I had to choose between my beer tasting/smelling of citrus or disinfectant, I know what I would go for :)

Answer (score 1):

A long soak with a baking soda solution has worked for me in the past.  I don't know what your measurements are, but I usually go of 1/3 to 1/2 cup into 6 gallons of hot water.  Soak overnight, rinse and then another hot soak with my standard cleaner PBW (powdered brewery wash).

Answer (score 0):

For non-metal containers I use bleach. Cheaper and works fine.

About 60 ml of bleach per 20 Liters of water (2 oz per 5 gallons), completely fill the vessel, cover it, ensures that the lid has contact with the solution, and I leave it rests for 3 nights (72 hours). I usually leave it there for 1 or 2 weeks until the next use, if I don't need the vessels before.

When you will use the vessel, just discard the solution (you can reuse the solution for others sanitizing/cleaning purposes in your home, like your toilet, sink, etc). Let the vessel dry, and it is cleaned, odorless, and sanitized.

(I guess that 24 hours can be enough but I never needed my vessels before 2 or 3 days, so I let them there until the next use).

**IMPORTANT: Never use the vessel with residues of bleach, ensure it is completely dry, or rinsed.** Chlorine residues will make off-flavors in your beer.

Answer (score 0):

Properly diluted bleach is cool but take great care not to use scented bleach, or you'll be worse off than when you started.  I've also swung between an acid and basic to clean things up.

BTW, extended chlorine baths can wreak havoc on stainless.

Comment: I never use chlorine on stainless steel, it almost makes it rust. Well ive tried everything I can think of to remove the smell including stuffing newspapers. I'm going to leave outside in the open air.

Answer (score -1):

I second what @brewchez said. We have used baking soda and hot water every time after brewing several hoppy IPAs, saisons, belgians, etc. A good soaking and rinse gets rid of the smell in the fermenter and in kegs.